# Install IPOPT on linux 20.04

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt, pyscipopt, coin-or

I'm a student and I'm new to Linux. I want to install IPOPT for solving a non-linear problem. I followed the instructions provided in this link: https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html.

I installed the following third-party dependencies: ThirdParty-ASL, ThirdParty-HSL, and ThirdParty-Mumps.

To install IPOPT, I performed the following steps:

```
Clone the IPOPT repository:
git clone https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt.git
cd Ipopt

mkdir build
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

These steps were completed successfully, but I am unsure how to configure IPOPT with HSL, ASL, and Mumps for solving non-linear problems. Additionally, I'm uncertain about how to verify that the installation was successful.

I would appreciate any guidance or assistance. Thank you.